# Is there a javascript gesture library that works with the Samsung galaxy tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, swipe, gestures

i have been experimenting with javascript gesture libraries. They all work great with the iPad mini, however, when I try them on my Samsung Galaxy Tab (GT-P7510, Android 4.04), the results are at best intermittent.

The best results I get are in portrait mode. In landscape mode, virtually nothing works.

I have tried, amongst others, the following libraries, all of which I found from this post: http://www.queness.com/post/11755/11-multi-touch-and-touch-events-javascript-libraries

- hammer.js
- quo.js
- touchy
- doubletap
- jgestures
- touchswipe

Touchswipe worked best, but all the others just didn't really play ball.

The Hammer page has a demo, which works fine on the ipad but not the android:

http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js/

So, does anybody know of any way I can get swipe gestures to play nice on my galaxy?

I have viewed the quirksmode page that a previous stackoverflow question pointed to, but that was out of date and no longer maintained, from what I could see. Also, it didn't actually mention any libraries.

Comment: Are you already working with a javascript library? Right now I'm working on a jQuery UI project and in order to add the gesture capability I use «jQuery UI Touch Punch» which plays very well with iPad & Android. http://touchpunch.furf.com/

Comment: I'm pretty stunned by the new sencha framework http://www.sencha.com/products/touch It's core is still Ext JS i reckon...

Comment: I think this question is likely to be closed: see [Why are “shopping list” questions bad?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad/158810#158810)

Comment: Sorry but I disagree. The arguments stated in that meta discussion don't fit here. For a start, I still haven't received an answer!

Comment: With regards to Touch Punch, I don't see how I could use that to implement a swipe gesture. It would be fine if I had an existing action like drag and drop, which I wanted to work with a tablet, but I want to get swipe working in a situation where there is no existing action. Swipe on an image to get the next image. That kind of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had good luck with this one:

https://github.com/HotStudio/touchy

It has long-press, pinch, rotate, and swipe gestures, and the code is fairly easy to customize.

Note that the combinations of gestures need to be handled-- for example, a swipe will almost always trigger a long touch as well, so you have to set flags or otherwise handle that.

Comment: Also, if you did not already try it, check out the development branch in the repo there-- it has updates that helped me

Comment: +1 for an actual answer!

I will experiment tonight and let you know how i get on.

Comment: Yes! Finally! That actually works. Thank you ever so much for pointing me in the right direction. It even works if I switch orientation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a CodePen gesture compare tool. http://jsfiddle.net/icoxfog417/uQBvP/

We abandon Hammer.JS after extensive work and moved to Quo which we are finding ok. Things may have changed and be different now.

```
  document.head.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeEnd', '<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi,width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />' );

$(function(){
  //initialization 
  $(".detector").bind("click touchstart",function(e){
    $(".detector").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");

    unbindLibrary();
    bindLibrary($(this).prop("id"));
  });

  //bind library to gesture pad
  bindLibrary = function(id){
    var $pad = $("#gesture-pad");
    var events = [];
    var eventStr = "";
    $("#" + id + "List li").each(function(){
      events.push($(this).text());
    })
    //make target event list from each library's gestureList
    eventStr = events.join(" ");

    switch(id){
      case "hammer":
        hammer = Hammer($pad.get(0), {
          prevent_default: true
        })
        .on(eventStr, logEvent);
        break;
      case "quojs":
        for(var i = 0;i<events.length;i++){
          $$("#gesture-pad").on(events[i], logEvent);
        }
        $$("#gesture-pad").on("touchstart",function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
        });
        break;
      case "touchSwipe":
        var options = {};
        var touchSwipeHandler = function(name){
          if(name.indexOf("pinch") < 0){
            return function(event, distance, duration, fingerCount){ 
                     var e = {}; e["type"] = name; logEvent(e);        
                   };
          }else{
            return function(e, direction, distance, d, f, pinchZoom){ 
                     var e = {}; e["type"] = name; logEvent(e);        
                   };
          }
        };

        for(var i = 0;i<events.length;i++){
            options[events[i]] = new touchSwipeHandler(events[i]); 
        }
        $pad.swipe(options);
        break;
      case "touchy" :
        var handler = function(name){
            return function(event, phase, $target, data){
                     var e = {}; e["type"] = name; logEvent(e);
                   }
        }
        for(var i = 0;i<events.length;i++){
            $pad.bind(events[i],new handler(events[i]));
        }
        break;      
    }
  }

  //unbind library from gesture pad
  unbindLibrary = function(){
    var element = $("#gesture-pad").clone();
    $("#gesture-pad").replaceWith(element);
    $(".gesturelist .selected").removeClass("selected");
  }

  //log detected gesture
  logEvent = function(e){
    $("#detected").text(e.type);
    var selected = $(".detector.selected").prop("id");
    $("#" + selected + "List li").each(function(){
        if($(this).text() == e.type){
            $(this).addClass("selected");
`enter code here`        };
    })          
    return false;
  }

  $(".detector").first().addClass("selected");
  bindLibrary($(".detector.selected").prop("id"));

})
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I tried several libraries and wasn't happy with any of them, so rolled my own.  It's MIT licensed and available at

https://github.com/aerik/GestureListener.js

with a test / demo page at

http://aerik.github.io/GestureListener/example.htm

I use it routinely on my Galaxy S4 phone, a couple of Ipads, and several Windows 8 touchscreen devices.  We are using it for production software at work.

Bug reports (with examples) welcome.